# Snake game doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

this is the part of the code isn't compiling. It will start and then stop when it gets here. I have a Char Map of [11][22] that is my board. What I'm trying to do is get the '*' to random generate, and act as the food for my snake.

```
srand(time(NULL));
int pellet=rand()%21;

while (GameRunning == true)
{
    for (int pellet = rand(); pellet % Map[11][22]; pellet++)
    {
        cout << '*';
    }
    system("cls");
```

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: Please avoid using IDE tags like visual-studio when your question does not regard the IDE. Those are used for questions about the *IDE* not code written with them.

Comment: `pellet % Map[11][22]`  Explain what that is supposed to do.

Comment: sorry about that I'm new to this website

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x013C921E in snake.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero. this is the error I'm getting.

Comment: my thought was that it would generate the '*' inside the map

Comment: @BenjaminKing If you can explain that line of code I pointed out and think about your explanation, you may have a clue as to why the error occurred.

Comment: @BenjaminKing `my thought was that it would generate the '*' inside the map `  No, what I mean is explain *technically* what that line does.  You couldn't have just pulled that line of code out of thin air.

Comment: @BenjaminKing I think you need to re-read the chapter on arrays.  I don't think you understand how to access certain array elements.  I could give a simple answer as to the reason you're getting the error, but you need to understand how to fix it, since I have no idea what your intentions are.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the pellet goes through a 2d array( map[11][22]) which is why I set the bounds at 21 counts through the array(pellet++)after it finds a empty space it displays the `*`

Comment: @BenjaminKing It isn't the boundaries of the array that is at fault.  It is the **access** to the array that is at fault.  See my answer.  You have a grid, and you want to access a point on that grid.  There is no point at location grid(11,22).  That's about as simple as I can explain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Map` is a two dimensional array of char:

`char Map[11][22];`

The problem is this line:

```
pellet % Map[11][22]
```

You are applying the modulus on an out-of-bounds entry in the map.

The map can be indexed from `0 to 10` for the first dimension, and `0 to 21` for the second dimension.  For example, `Map[0][0]` is a valid entry, as is `Map[4][7]`, but `Map[11][22]` is not a valid entry.

At this out-of-bounds entry, the value there by chance happens to be a 0, causing the divide by zero error (calculating `n mod 0` results in this error).

---

To try to explain as simply as possible, think of a 2-dimensional array as a grid.  In your case the grid has 11 rows and 22 columns.

So now you want to get to a certain point on that grid, say the third row, fifth column.  To do that, you would say `Mat[2][4]`.  The reason why it isn't `Mat[3][5]` is that in C++, array indices start at 0, not 1.  Now given this, you are accessing `Mat[11][22]`, which is one row and one column out of bounds.

Yes, you declared the array as having a size of 11 rows and 22 columns, but that is only relevant when telling C++ how large the array is (when you declare the array).  When you need to access the various elements in the array, you have to use 0-based indexing to get to the entry you are interested in.

Follow ups:  Any good C++ book explains this in better detail than I could.

Comment: wow thanks alot now I just need to code for when the S(which is what im using for the body of my snake) come in contact with the * it will ad body to my snake which im thinking I can use an if statement

Comment: Could you help me with the code when the character and pellet are in the same place